# Recompiling a SP in live environment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, recompile

I have a Stored Procedure which I want to recompile. is it safe to do that in a Live environment ? Because there's continuous flow of data which is being processed by the Stored Procedure and the SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending upon the method used (i.e. do not drop and recreate the procedure using the `WITH RECOMPILE` option), this is perfectly safe to execute on the Live environment.

If using `sp_recompile`, the stored procedure will simply be flagged to cause a new query plan to be calculated the very next time it is executed.  This may cause a very small delay whilst the new query plan is compiled but it will be negligible:

```
exec sp_recompile N'<your procedure>'
```

Comment: So It would be safe to go with the command exec sp_recompile right ?

Comment: @RamMehta It will be safe to use this.  As I say, it simply flags the procedure to be recompiled the very next time it is executed (which will happen automatically).